# navbar scroll (position: sticky) stops working after the 'about' section

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navbar, sticky

I used sticky as the navbar's position. it worked all the way until it hit the end of the about section.

I want the navbar to move with the scroll all the way until it reaches the top where it then becomes fixed throughout the remainder of the website.

I have an up-to-date version of chrome (107.0.5304.87) and according to
https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky the browser is compatible with 'sticky'.

I wondered whether display:flex and justify-content could be interfering (read that display:flex and position:absolute are not a good match) and took those away. Nothing changed.

current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title id="title">Fantasy Book Covers</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="black_background">
      <div class="fadein_1">
      <p id="beginning_quote">"Each touch...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fadein_2">
      <p id="ending_quote">brings the magic to life"</p>
      </div>
    
    <div class="intro_images">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5pcaukzdu8drjx/Pasted%20Graphic%2018.png?dl=1"/>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fdnhyueimm3xhu/Pasted%20Graphic%2016.png?dl=1"/>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/496kpiry8x30xzn/Pasted%20Graphic%2017.png?dl=1"/>
    </div>  
  
    <section id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <p id="about">About</p>
    <p id="service">Service</p>
    <div id="home_button"></div>
    <p id="faqs">FAQs</p>
    <p id="contact">Contact</p>
  </div>
    </section>

  <div class="about_section">
    <p>We believe as fantasy-book enthusiasts that to truly experience the magic of a book, one must “feel” its essence. Our job is to transport you to magical worlds with our</p>
    <p> <i>handmade, leather book covers.</i></p>
    <p>Choose any book, from any author, and we will bring their story to life.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="traditional_section">
    <div id="traditional_image"></div>
    <div id="traditional_p">
      <p id="traditional_title">Traditional</p>
      <p id="lorem_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>amet,consectetur adipiscing <br>elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br>incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum</p>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```
.black_background{
position: absolute;
margin-left:-2%;
margin-top:-2%;
width: 1461px;
height: 365px;
background: #000000;
}

.intro_images{
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  max-width:5%;
  height:25%;
  left: 39%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#beginning_quote{
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 8%;
font-family: Baskerville;
font-size: 48px;
color: #995DBE;
animation: animate;
}
#beginning_quote::first-letter{
  font-size: 70px;
}

#ending_quote{
margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: -3%;
font-family: Baskerville;
font-size: 48px;
color: #DDA5FE;
}

.fadein_1{
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
0%{opacity:0;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}

.fadein_2{
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
0%{opacity:0;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}

#nav_bar{
  margin-top: 33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  height:13%;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
}



#about, #service, #faqs, #contact{
  position: relative;
  margin-top:0.9%;
}

.about_section{
  color:black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family:Baskerville;
  font-size: 30px;
}

i{
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left:20%;
}

.traditional_section{
  background-color:rgba(36, 2, 56, 0.45);
  width: 848px;
  height: 524px;
  margin-left: 21%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
```

I also tried JS version:

```
const header = document.getElementById("header");
const navbar = document.getElementById("nav_bar");

window.onscroll = function(){
  if(window.pageYOffset >= navbar.offsetTop){
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  }
  else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
};
```

```
#nav_bar{
  margin-top: 33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  height:13%;
}

.sticky{
 position: sticky;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

Again it worked until it hit the the end of the about section where it stopped working.

I am not familiar with jquery if that is what I have to use to make it work.
I would prefer not to use fixed position if there is a way to get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work at the end with this following code:

```css
.black_background{
position:relative;
margin-left:-2%;
margin-top:-1%;
width: 1461px;
height: 365px;
background: #000000;
}

#quote{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width:100%;
}

#beginning_quote{
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 8%;
font-family: Baskerville;
font-size: 48px;
color: #995DBE;
animation: animate;
}

#beginning_quote::first-letter{
  font-size: 70px;
}

#ending_quote{
margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: -3%;
font-family: Baskerville;
font-size: 48px;
color: #DDA5FE;
}

.fadein_1{
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
0%{opacity:0;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}

.fadein_2{
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
0%{opacity:0;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}

#nav_bar{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  height:13%;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}

#about, #service, #faqs, #contact{
  position: relative;
  margin-top:0.9%;
}
.about_section{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family:Baskerville;
  font-size: 30px;
}

i{
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left:20%;
}

.traditional_section{
  background-color:rgba(36, 2, 56, 0.45);
  width: 848px;
  height: 524px;
  margin-left: 21%;
  margin-top:35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title id="title">Fantasy Book Covers</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="black_background">
      <div id="quote">
      <div class="fadein_1">
      <p id="beginning_quote">"Each touch...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fadein_2">
      <p id="ending_quote">brings the magic to life"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    

  <div id="nav_bar">
    <p id="about">About</p>
    <p id="service">Service</p>
    <p id="home_button"></p>
    <p id="faqs">FAQs</p>
    <p id="contact">Contact</p>
    </div>
   

  <div class="about_section">
    <p>We believe as fantasy-book enthusiasts that to truly experience the magic of a book, one must “feel” its essence. Our job is to transport you to magical worlds with our</p>
    <p> <i>handmade, leather book covers.</i></p>
    <p>Choose any book, from any author, and we will bring their story to life.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="traditional_section">
    <div id="traditional_image"></div>
    <div id="traditional_p">
      <p id="traditional_title">Traditional</p>
      <p id="lorem_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>amet,consectetur adipiscing <br>elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br>incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your HTML. You don't have proper closing tags for the divs with `class="black_background"` and `class="traditional_section"`. After you add closing tags your css will look diffrent and relatively broken. Try to rewrite your css with proper HTML tags I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hey, good spotting, but that didn't help.